# CakePHP 2.1 : HABTM saveAssociated and keep exists data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a little problem with saveAssociated and exists entries :(

**Models:**

*Ingredient.php*

```
<?php

class Ingredient extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Ingredient';
    public $hasMany = array('IngredientsRecipes');

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Recipe' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Recipe',
                'joinTable'              => 'ingredients_recipes',
                'foreignKey'             => 'ingredient_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'recipe_id',
                'unique'                 => 'keepExisting',
                'conditions'             => '',
                'fields'                 => '',
                'order'                  => '',
                'limit'                  => '',
                'offset'                 => '',
                'finderQuery'            => '',
                'deleteQuery'            => '',
                'insertQuery'            => ''
            )
    );
 }
```

*Recipe.php*

```
<?php
class Recipe extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Recipe';
    public $hasMany = array('IngredientsRecipes');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Ingredient' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Ingredient',
                'joinTable'              => 'ingredients_recipes',
                'foreignKey'             => 'recipe_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'ingredient_id',
                'unique'                 => 'keepExisting',
                'conditions'             => '',
                'fields'                 => '',
                'order'                  => '',
                'limit'                  => '',
                'offset'                 => '',
                'finderQuery'            => '',
                'deleteQuery'            => '',
                'insertQuery'            => ''
            )
    );
}
```

*IngredientRecipe.php*

```
<?php
class IngredientRecipe extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'IngredientsRecipes';
    public $belongsTo = array('Ingredient', 'Recipe');
}
```

**Views:**

*View/IngredientsRecipes/add.ctp*

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('IngredientRecipe'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Ingredient.ingredient', array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Ingredient')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Recipe.recipe', array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Recipe')); ?>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**Contollers:**

*IngredientRecipeController.php*

```
<?php
class IngredientRecipeController extends AppController {

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     if(!empty($this->request->data)) {
       $ingredients_comma_separated = explode(',', $this->request->data['Ingredient']['ingredient']);
       $recipes_comma_separated = explode(',', $this->request->data['Recipe']['recipe']);
       $recipes = array();
         foreach($ingredients_comma_separated as $ingredient){
         $recipes['Ingredient']['ingredient'] = trim($ingredient);
         foreach($recipes_comma_separated as $recipe){
         $recipes['Recipe']['recipe'] = trim($recipe);
        if ($this->IngredientRecipe->saveAssociated($recipes, array('deep' => true, 'validate' => 'first'))) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Saved.');
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

**MySQL Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ingredients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ingredient` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ingredient` (`ingredient`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ingredients_recipes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipe` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `recipe` (`recipe`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**My Question:**

How i can keep exists data in recipes & ingredients fields and continue saving associated data in ingredients_recipes field ?

Answer (score 3):

`'unique'                 => 'keepExisting',`
Isn't meant for this. What it does, is keeping the existing information of additional rows in the join table, but it still acts the same as `'unique' => true`.

See:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#ref-habtm-arrays

What you need to do is set it to false.

Comment: nothing changes .... i become error "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry"

Comment: I see you're using a hasmany through joinmodel AND a habtm on the same models, that's just wrong, pick one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Since the recipe and ingredient records already exist, you should be able to get their id. Then when saving data, you simply supply the id to save the new relation, like

```
dataArray = array(
    'recipe'=>array('id'=>$recipeId),
    'ingredient'=>array('id'=>$ingredientId)
);
```

In this way records in `recipe` and `ingredient` tables would not be modified or duplicated.

If your inputs from form is text instead selections like a drop-down-list, you probably need to manually find the id before saving the relation.

Answer (score 0):

make unique=false in both Recipe and Ingredient Model
and from Recipe controller do

```
$this->Recipe->saveAll($this->request->data)
```

I think this will work